# Is there any security concerns to enable http options?

Tags: security

My recent vulnerability assessment report flagged the HTTP OPTIONS is enable as unsecure practice.  However, developer told me that it is necessary to enable so that end user may use the MS Explorer to copy / upload files.

I understand HTTP OPTIONS should not be enable in Internet facing applications, to preempt hacker from finding out what are the methods available to communicate with the web server.  But, does the same concern applicable to Sharepoint, in particular, for this use case, this is an intranet application.

Thank you for enlightening me...

Comment: It all depends on the architecture of your network. Do you have single site or multiple (branch offices). On single site the risk is low. But if you have branch offices then the network architecture matters. What is your case?